# Mysqlcppconn8 and cmake error at build in linux

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, cmake

I'm trying to build simple example with new `libmysqlcppconn` version 8 using `cmake`, I download the connector and build and install from source. But I get error when I try to build my helloworld using `cmake` or `Clion` run

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/hellogcp.dir/src/main.cpp.o: en la función `mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_common<mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail>::~Result_common()':
/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/result.h:71: referencia a `mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail::~Result_detail()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/hellogcp.dir/src/main.cpp.o: en la función `mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_common<mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail>::~Result_common()':
/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/result.h:71: referencia a `mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail::~Result_detail()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/hellogcp.dir/src/main.cpp.o: en la función `mysqlx::abi2::r0::Result::~Result()':
/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/result.h:71: referencia a `mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail::~Result_detail()' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/hellogcp.dir/src/main.cpp.o: en la función `mysqlx::abi2::r0::Result::~Result()':
/usr/include/mysqlx/devapi/result.h:71: referencia a `mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail::~Result_detail()' sin definir
```

I test with

```
find_library(MYSQL_LIB mysqlcppconn8)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MYSQL_LIB})
```

But the error is the same with or without `find_library`.

If I use:

```
set(EXTRA_LIBRARY "mysqlcppconn8")
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: can not be found -lmysqlcppconn8
/usr/bin/ld: can not be found -lmysqlcppconn8
```

with:

> g++ -std=c++11 -I .../include -L .../lib64 src/main.cpp -lmysqlcppconn8 -o app

Builds perfectly. But if I remove `-lmysqlcppconn8`, I get the same error than `cmake`.

How can I add the `-lmysqlcppconn8` to `cmake`?

Comment: The error you got is because the absence of the linking to the needed library. Do you mean that the error is caused by `find_library` approach? Otherwise, what do you mean by "but dont work" when describe that approach?

Comment: the error is the same with or without find_library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding the library with extension

```
if (BUILD_MODE STREQUAL "Docker")
    message("***************************** USING STATIC LIBS **************************************")
    add_compile_definitions(STATIC_CONCPP)
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-static")
    set(DCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a)
    find_library(PISTACHE_LIB libpistache.a)
    find_library(MYSQL_LIB libmysqlcppconn8-static.a)
    set(MY_LIBS ${PISTACHE_LIB} ${MYSQL_LIB})
else()
    message("***************************** USING SHARED LIBS **************************************")
    find_library(PISTACHE_LIB libpistache.so)
    find_library(MYSQL_LIB libmysqlcppconn8.so)
    set(MY_LIBS ${PISTACHE_LIB} ${MYSQL_LIB})
endif (BUILD_MODE STREQUAL "Docker")
unset(BUILD_MODE CACHE)
```